# Iterable and iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iterable

```
with open("weather_data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.reader(data_file)
    for x in data:
        print(x)
```

My understand is: `csv.reader(data_file)` is an iterable, it calls `iter(self)` and return _i as an iterator. This `_i` calls `next()` each time to enter next iteration. However,I use `print(help(csv.reader(data_file))` and found that

```
 Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __iter__(self, /)
 |      Implement iter(self).
 |  
 |  __next__(self, /)
 |      Implement next(self).
```

My question is, the method `__next__(self, /)` here is exactly the same thing that was called by `_i` every time? Does `_i` also carry the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csv.reader` object is its own iterator. This is a common practice for iterables which are single-pass (i.e. can only be run through once). We can confirm this by inspection.

```
>>> data
<_csv.reader object at 0x7fe5d4a057b0>
>>> iter(data)
<_csv.reader object at 0x7fe5d4a057b0> # Note: Same as above
>>> id(data)
140625091516336
>>> id(iter(data))
140625091516336 # Note: Same as above
>>> data is iter(data)
True
```

Compare this to something like a list, which is an iterable but is not itself an iterator.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
>>> iter(lst)
<list_iterator object at 0x7fe5d59747f0> # Note: NOT the same as before
>>> lst is iter(lst)
False
```

This allows us to iterate over a list several times by calling `iter(lst)` multiple times, since each call gives us a fresh iterator. But your `csv.reader` object is single-pass, so we only have the one iterator to it.

In Python, every iterator is an iterable, but not every iterable is an iterator. From [the glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)

> Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in most places where other iterables are accepted.